ChartView.mapToValue() returns an incorrect result, but approaches correct as I zoom in
Python 3.9.1 / PySide6 6.8.0.1
I have a ChartView with a LineSeries in it and the value that is being returned from the mapToValue() function is not correct.
The LineSeries is populated through the Python backend and the axes are being configured (in the Python backend) so that the whole data series will fit in the ChartView (with some "margin" between the data and the edges of the ChartView). There is a Label that follows the mouse cursor and gets populated with (what should be) the x-y value at the mouse cursor in the plotArea Rectangle of the ChartView.
The x-y value is incorrect, and to such a degree that I can't chalk it up to precision, except that, as I zoom in, the value displayed gets more and more accurate. As the image below shows, I have my mouse cursor nearly at (-20, 2200), but the value displayed is so incorrect that the displayed y-coordinate is greater than the value at the next grid line.

Here is a snippet from the JS file containing the function that moves and populates the Label:
var pt = Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y)
var val = chartView.mapToValue(pt, chartView.series(0))
var units = ""
graphValueLabel.x = mouse.x + 15
graphValueLabel.y = mouse.y + 5
if (graphType == "raw") { units = "ms" }
else { units = "s" }
graphValueLabel.text = "Time: " + val.x.toPrecision(3) + units + ", Value: " + Math.round(val.y)

And here is the Python method that configures the axes:
@Slot(QValueAxis, QValueAxis, str)
def configure_axes(self, xAxis, yAxis, type):
    if type == 'raw':
        xAxis.setMin(self.time_vals[-1] - RAW_CHART_X_ZOOM_SPAN_MS)
        xAxis.setMax(self.time_vals[-1])
    else:
        x_span = self.time_vals[-1] - self.time_vals[0]
        x_margin = x_span * AXIS_INIT_ZOOM_MARGIN_FACT
        xAxis.setMin(self.time_vals[0] - x_margin)
        xAxis.setMax(self.time_vals[-1] + x_margin)
    
    y_span = self.max_y - self.min_y
    y_margin = y_span * AXIS_INIT_ZOOM_MARGIN_FACT

    if y_span / Y_AXIS_INIT_TICKS_PER_SPAN < TICK_INTERVAL_100:
        yAxis.setTickInterval(TICK_INTERVAL_100)
    elif y_span / Y_AXIS_INIT_TICKS_PER_SPAN < TICK_INTERVAL_200:
        yAxis.setTickInterval(TICK_INTERVAL_200)
    else:
        yAxis.setTickInterval(TICK_INTERVAL_500)

    yAxis.setMin(self.min_y - y_margin)
    yAxis.setMax(self.max_y + y_margin)

I'm at a loss here for where to look next. If any additional information is needed (how the data is populated, how the ChartView or LineSeries are configured, etc, I'm happy to provide that information.
